# SQLite Error when try to get two fileds from database

Tags: android, sqlite

That's my codes for database

```
public ArrayList<SubCatInfo> getSubCatByCatIdAndtypeName(int id,
            String typeName) {

ArrayList<SubCatInfo> list = new ArrayList<SubCatInfo>();
        Cursor c = this.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_SUBCAT
                + " WHERE cat_id='" + id + " AND typeName='" + typeName,null);
```

the logcat shows,

```
01-28 12:28:46.693: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(260): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tbl_subcategories WHERE cat_id='11 AND typeName='1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is error because maybe you are formatting query wrong.

---

```
Cursor c = this.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_SUBCAT + " WHERE cat_id='" + id + " AND typeName='" + typeName,null);
```

---

use below code instead of above

---

```
Cursor c = this.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_SUBCAT + " WHERE cat_id=" + id + " AND typeName=" + typeName,null);
```

Comment: HI chirag, your codes work fine 100%, thanks you save my day :)

Comment: its my pleasure,pls tick my ans as right by clicking right side of my ans (on checkmark) if u find my ans is useful.this will helpful to others to find ans